# Dynamodb data model for process/transaction monitoring

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, data-modeling, nosql

I am wanting to keep track of multi stage processing job.

Likely just need the following fields

```
batchId (guid) | eventId (guid) | statusId (int) | timestamp | message (string)
```

There are relatively small number of events per batch.

**I want to be able to easily query events that have a statusId less than *n* (still being processed or didn't finish processing).**

Would using multiple rows for each status change, and querying for latest status be the best approach? I would use global secondary index but StatusId does not seem like a good candidate for hashkey (less than 10 statuses).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using multiple rows for every status change, if you updated the same event row instead, you could use a technique described in the [DynamoDB documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.UniformWorkload) in the section 'Use a Calculated Value'. Basically this would involve adding another attribute (say 'derivedStatusId') which would be derived by appending a random number to statusId at the time of writing to DynamoDB. For example, for a statusId of 2, derivedStatusId could be one of {"2-00", "2-01", .. "2-99"}. Setting up a Global Secondary Index on derivedStatusId would give you some fan-out that will help in preventing the index from becoming hot.

If you are sure that you will use this index for **only** unfinished events, then removing the derivedStatusId attribute from the record when it transitions to a finished status will remove it from index as well - which may be a good property if events are expected to finish processing eventually, and if they stay around forever. This technique is called "Sparse Index" and is described in more detail [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForGSI.html#GuidelinesForGSI.SparseIndexes).

From your question, it seems like keeping status history recording is a desired property (I assume this because you want to have multiple rows for status changes). Consider putting this historical information in the same row. DynamoDB supports list data types and also has a generous 400KB item limit which may just allow you to capture all the desired historical information in the same record.

Comment: A global secondary index on derivedStatusId: statusId+(eventId mod n) would make it non hot, but would still have to perform n queries to get all items correct?

Comment: How performant would Scan on this sparse global secondary index be? Because I guess a scan would work for my use case since there won't be many unfinished items at any one time.

Comment: If you remove finished items from the index like mentioned above, a scan would be quite efficient since the global secondary index would only contain unfinished items.